# Assign 2d std_logic_vector with another 1d std_logic_vector in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I have this port

```
PORT (
    A : IN  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 downto 0);
    B : IN  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 downto 0);
    C : IN  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 downto 0);
    F : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 downto 0);
);
```

and this signal

```
SIGNAL data : std_logic_2d(31 downto 0, 2 downto 0);
```

I need to assign data(all,0) with A and data(all,1) with B and so on
like that

```
data(?,0) <= A;
data(?,1) <= B;
data(?,2) <= C;
```

what can I put instead of "**?**" in the code to perform it??

Comment: There's nothing you can put in place of those question marks. Slices are one-dimensional arrays. How about a [mcve] which would include the declaration of type std_logic_2d? You should likely be using a function or a loop statement in a place appropriate for a sequential statement, or a generate statement in a place appropriate for a concurrent statement. If type std_logic_2d has an element type of std_logic, it isn't closely related to std_logic_vector and can't be type converted (IEEE Std 1076-2008 8.5 Slice names, 9.3.6 Type conversions).

Comment: You could use a jagged array (an array of arrays) instead of a 2D array...

Comment: You need a process with a for-loop or generate loop to iterate all indices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 1 - process and for-loop:**

A process is used to host a sequential for loop. You need to add all read signals to the sensitivity list: `A`, `B`, `C`.

```
process(A, B, C)
begin
  for i in A'range loop
    data(i, 0) <= A(i);
    data(i, 1) <= B(i);
    data(i, 2) <= C(i);
  end loop;
end process;
```

**Solution 2 - for-generate:**

A generate loop is used to create lots of concurrent assignments.

```
gen: for i in A'range generate
  data(i, 0) <= A(i);
  data(i, 1) <= B(i);
  data(i, 2) <= C(i);
end generate;
```

**Solution 3 - a assignment procesdure:**

A procedure is used to encapsulate the assignment to rows.

```
procedure assign_col(signal slm : out T_SLM; slv : std_logic_vector; constant ColIndex : natural) is
  variable temp : std_logic_vector(slm'range(1));
begin
  temp := slv;
    for i in temp'range loop
      slm(i, ColIndex)  <= temp(i);
  end loop;
end procedure;
```

Source: [`PoC.vectors.assign_col`](https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC/blob/master/src/common/vectors.vhdl?ts=2#L252-L259)

Usage:

```
assign_col(data, A, 0);
assign_col(data, B, 1);
assign_col(data, C, 2);
```

The package [`PoC.vectors`](https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC/blob/master/src/common/vectors.vhdl?ts=2) contains a lot of new types, functions and procedures to handle true `std_logic` based 2D arrays in VHDL.

Comment: Don't you mean to call assign_col three times instead of assign_row?

Comment: @user1155120 You're right. I used the wrong procedure in the example.